# Почему функция ограничения ввода работает не так как планировалась

Tags: c

Написал небольшую функцию для нее передаваемые значения есть адрес строковой переменой,  и целое число (числом является кол-во символов, которое помещается в строку). Хочу сделать так чтобы пользователь не мог ввести больше символов чем положено, ну и пустую строку он тоже не смог ввести.
Условие на пустую строку функция проверяет, но когда я ввожу больше символов чем положено пишет ERROR.Try again, но далее выходит из функции. Вроде как я очищаю поток ввода, но это не помогает.

```
char* ENTER_STRING(char user_string[],int a)
{
    while (strlen(fgets(user_string, a, stdin)) == a - 1 || strcmp(user_string, "\n") == 0)
    {
            printf("ERROR.Try again\n-> ");
            fflush(stdin);
    }
    user_string[strcspn(user_string, "\n")] = 0;
    return user_string;
}
```

Comment: [`fflush(stdin);`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979217/9630063) == UB

Comment: Используйте fgetc, getc.

Comment: @こきん при использовании ```while (getchar() != '\n');``` просит ввести пустую строку, что при использовании программы не удобно. То есть после ERROR.Try again сначала нужно нажать enter а после вводить нужное значение.

Comment: `strlen(fgets(...))` уже неправильно. При ошибке ввода или конце файла fgets вернет NULL, следовательно strlen упадет. Не стоит писать такие сложные конструкции в условиях цикла. Делайте проверки в его теле и выходите по break. ***Вместо fflush(stdin) читайте getchar() пока не прочтете '\n'.*** И не забывайте правильно обрабатывать и возвращать конец файла в своей функции (особенно отследите момент, когда последний символ в файле (потоке stdin) **не  '\n'**)